# How to accept weight data from Detecto AS-350D

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I've found a scale, Detecto AS-350D (http://cardinal-detecto.centralcarolinascale.com/AS-PC-Computer.htm), that hooks up to a computer. I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to get the information (weight) from it.  I've looked around but can't seem to find any information on it.  I've never wrote a program where I accepted data from a device likes this so kind of confused where to look. Thanks.

Update: I'm coding in VB, and the device connects to the computer via serial port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a serial port programming language in C#. maybe you want to try it. It also has a built-in debugger and it requires .NET Framework 3.5 or above. you do NOT have to install any other programming tools. It is freely available on sourceforge.

If you create a driver simply with the following state, you will be able to get the data from the serial port.

```
state Init
  recv();
end state
```

[Download Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/anyserialport/)

For more information, please visit [Project homepage](http://www.anyserialport.com)

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.